# How to use link_to in rails to load html.erb page in controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Im very new to rails, will be thankful if any one answer..!  Im  not able to load customers_list.html.erb

This is my customers/index.html.erb

```
<li><%= link_to "Edit", edit_customers_path(customers) %></li>
```

This is my  customers_controllers

```
def edit
render:"customers_list" // customers_list.html.erb in customers view
end
```

This is my  routes.rb

```
resources :customers
```

error:

```
undefined local variable or method `customers'
```

Comment: How do you learn rails, I wonder? Any rails book covers this

Comment: im just learning it of my own by following http://guides.rubyonrails.org/layouts_and_rendering.html --  guides

Comment: Please provide either the error you are receiving or the expected behavior compared to the current behavior in the view.  Based on the current information provided the question is somewhat vague.  Also, you could move customers_list.html.erb to edit.html.erb and completely leave out the render line.

Comment: You'll get much better results by reading a proper book. Rails guides are not good for learning the tech from scratch.

Comment: will u please advice me , which one will be better book to follow

Comment: [Agile Web Development with Rails](http://pragprog.com/book/rails3/agile-web-development-with-rails): pick the right edition

Comment: also http://ruby.railstutorial.org/ruby-on-rails-tutorial-book

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, `index.html.erb` is the right place to list the customers. So, you don't need `customers_list`.

```
#controller
def index
  @customers = Customer.all
end

#view (index.html.erb)
<% @customers.each do |customer| %>
  <%= customer.name %> #assuming customer has the attribute name
<% end %>
```

if you are trying to edit one customer, you can add it to the loop in the index view:

```
<% @customers.each do |customer| %>
  <%= customer.name %>
  <%= link_to 'Edit', edit_customer_path(customer) %>
<% end %>
```

However, based on your `<%= link_to "Edit", edit_customers_path(customers) %>`, you should think:

- What is `edit_customers_path`? take a look [here](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#paths-and-urls). You can also see the routes using [rake routes](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#seeing-existing-routes-with-rake).
- what is `customers`? you haven't defined it.

if you define it in your controller, you might be able to use it in your view:

```
def index
...
@customer = Customer.find(1)
end
```

In your view:

```
<%= link_to 'Edit', edit_customer_path(@customer) %>
```

I hope it helps you in some way....